# How to enable RSS on a virtual NIC created on a HyperV host?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I created an "[Internal virtual switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines)" to allow the Hyper-V virtual machine to communicate with the host. This step creates a virtual NIC on the host.

This virtual NIC however does not have the option to enable RSS (receive side scaling) causing a bottleneck on sends from the VM.

Is there a way to enable RSS on this virtual NIC on the host machine? Note that there is an option to enable RSS inside the VM.

Also, is there any better/faster way of communication from the VM to the host for large send payloads?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn383582(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: the msdn article talks about enabling RSS inside the VM; I am trying to enable RSS on the host (on the virtual NIC)

Comment: It appears the problem has been resolved in server 2016. I see there is the RSS enabled by default on the host virtual NIC. It would be nice to somehow port this back to server 2k12r2 though.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you cant on Server 2012R2 like you said you can on Server 2016.

I never needed to transfer that much data between the host machine and virtual machine before.

All of my hyper hosts usually a physical adapter or set of teamed/ bonded adapters for the virtual switch and separate adapter for the host. Which in 2012R2 would allow the use RSS or VMQ for all the machines.